# How to get current month datas from mysql using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have table of records and need to get only current month records.

CODE:

```
          let startDate = req.body.startDate
          let endDate = req.body.endDate
       
           let result = await caseRegistration.findByDate({ pathology_id : req.body.pathology_id,
                                                            created_at: {
                                                                   '>=': new Date(startDate),
                                                                   '<=': new Date(endDate)
                                                                 }
                                                           })
```

Above code I am passing particular dates to get records. But my requirement is If request doesn't have any date then I want to get only current month data. Can you please help me?

Comment: Check if startDate and endDate are empty.If both are empty find first date and last date of current month. And in this case startDate=firstDateOfCurrentMonth and endDate=endDateOfCurrentMonth

Comment: Thanks for your solution. One more thing, In this code, created_at <= req.body.endDate , but its giving only before the enddate records not giving equal date of that record. what could be the issue?? For Ex: 21/8/2020 => endDate, result is till 20/8/2020 its not giving 21th date records.

Comment: Check the SQL query and also verify that what is the value of endDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If startDate and endDate are empty find first date and last date of current month by using this :

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDateOfCurrentMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var endDateOfCurrentMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

Now you can assign these dates to startDate and endDate

```
statDate=firstDateOfCurrentMonth;  
endDate=endDateOfCurrentMonth;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var date = new Date(); 

var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(), 1);  
                
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth(), daysInMonth(date.getMonth()+1, 
                        date.getFullYear())); 

firstDay=>Tue Sep 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time) 
 
lastDay=> Wed Sep 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Please take care of timezone & date formate you want(it could be any)